# Не компилируется код парсера

Tags: c++

Пишу парсер даты. Код не компилируется. Заголовок  подключил, почему не создается поток?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void Parse(string& s) {
    istream date_stream(s);
    int year;
    date_stream >> year;
    date_stream.ignore();
    int month;
    date_stream >> month;
    date_stream.ignore();
    int day;
    date_stream >> day;

    cout << year << " " << month << " " << day;
}

int main() {
    string text;
    cin >> text;
    Parse(text);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Надо полагать, что компилятор выдал текст с ошибками почему не компилируется?

Comment: Вам точно нужен [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)? Не `istringstream`? Вобщем, замените `istream` на `istringstream`, и все скомпилируется...

Comment: @Harry Да, все верно, не правильно выбрал поток. Нужно "istringstream".

Comment: @VTT Компилятор ошибку конечно выдал.("error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(std::string&)'|"). Но, к сожалению, я не понял по ней, что ошибка в слове. Слова созвучные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение проблемы заключается в изменении istream на istringstream.